# How do you create a MUL key in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, mysql-workbench

Also, why should someone use a MUL key (advantages/ disadvantages)?

The reason I ask is I'm trying to learn more about MySQL by creating the Media Wiki (Wikipedia) database from scratch using the wiki design on MySQL Workbench.

```
mysql> describe ipblocks;
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+----------------+----------------+
| Field                | Type             | Null | Key | Default        | Extra          |
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+----------------+----------------+
| ipb_id               | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL           | auto_increment |
| ipb_address          | tinyblob         | NO   | MUL | NULL           |                |
| ipb_user             | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0              |                |
| ipb_by               | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0              |                |
```

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Ipblocks_table
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Database_layout

Answer (score 1):

When you create a non-unique index, `describe` command shows it as "MUL" . Check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html for more details.